# Problems with comparison between two inputs in for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, input

I need help with this problem. I am supposed to be making a program where I need to compare 10 stock prices and find the largest increase in a day in the numbers using the program. The program can only use for loops/if else and main method. I am using scanner to obtain the ints for the stock prices. Everytime i run the code, all i get is the last values that i put into the scanner. PLEASE HELP. Code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//48  54  49  47  62  64  59  70  75  82
class Increase
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   final int Days = 10;
   int highval = 0;
   int lowval = 0; 
   int increase = 0; 
   int day = 0;
   System.out.print("Enter the stock prices for " + Days + " number of days.");
   int x = in.nextInt();

   for (int i = 0; i < Days-1; i++)
   {
    int y = in.nextInt();
     if (increase < (y - x));
     { 
       increase = (y - x);
       highval = y;
       lowval = x;
       day = i; 
     }
    x = y;
   }    

   System.out.println("The largest increase is " + increase);
   System.out.println("from  " +lowval + " to " + highval );
   System.out.println("between days " + day + " and " + (day + 1));
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are taking more than one input from the scanner.

Comment: int x = in.nextInt();                                                     for (int i = 0; i < Days-1; i++)
   {
    int y = in.nextInt();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the ; in the line 
if (increase < (y - x)); (empty assignment)

which is causing the below loop to be executed always.

```
{
increase = (y - x);
       highval = y;
       lowval = x;
       day = i; 

}
```

to fix change as below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    class Increase
    {
     public static void main (String [] args)
     {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       final int Days = 10;
       int highval = 0;
       int lowval = 0; 
       int increase = 0; 
       int day = 0;
       System.out.print("Enter the stock prices for " + Days + " number of days.");
       int x = in.nextInt();

       for (int i = 0; i < Days-1; i++)
       {
        int y = in.nextInt();
         if (increase < (y - x))
         { 
           increase = (y - x);
           highval = y;
           lowval = x;
           day = i; 
         }
        x = y;
       }    

       System.out.println("The largest increase is " + increase);
       System.out.println("from  " +lowval + " to " + highval );
       System.out.println("between days " + day + " and " + (day + 1));
     }
    }
```